# Flutter: ToggledButtons using FlatButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Dart and Flutter and I would like to know what do you think about this code and if it's any way that I could improve it :).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Checked Listview',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ToggleButtons(
        selectedWidget: <Widget>[
          Text("select_1"),
          Text("select_2"),
          Text("select_3")
        ],
        unselectedWidget: <Widget>[
          Text("unselect_1"),
          Text("unselect_2"),
          Text("unselect_3")
        ],
        onPressed: (elem, isSelected) {
          if (isSelected) {
            print(elem);
          }
        },
        shouldBeJustOneSelected: true,
      )),
    );
  }
}

class ToggleButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> selectedWidget;
  final List<Widget> unselectedWidget;
  final bool shouldBeJustOneSelected;
  final Function(Widget widget, bool isSelected) onPressed;

  ToggleButtons(
      {Key key,
      this.selectedWidget,
      this.unselectedWidget,
      this.shouldBeJustOneSelected,
      this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  _ToggleButtonsState createState() => _ToggleButtonsState();
}

class _ToggleButtonsState extends State<ToggleButtons> {
  List<Widget> _originalButtons = List<Widget>();
  List<Widget> _choosedButtons = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _choosedButtons = widget.unselectedWidget;
  }

  buildList() {
    if (_originalButtons.isNotEmpty) {
      _originalButtons.clear();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < _choosedButtons.length; i++) {
      _originalButtons.add(FlatButton(
        child: _choosedButtons[i],
        onPressed: () {
          print(i);
          rebuildList(i);
        },
      ));
    }
    return _originalButtons;
  }

  List<Widget> deepCopyList(List<Widget> list) {
    var newList = List<Widget>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      newList.add(list[i]);
    }
    return newList;
  }

  List<Widget> deepCopyListElement(List<Widget> list, Widget elem, int ind) {
    var newList = List<Widget>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (i == ind) {
        newList.add(elem);
      } else {
        newList.add(list[i]);
      }
    }
    return newList;
  }

  void rebuildList(int ind) {
    setState(() {
      Widget newElement = _choosedButtons[ind] == widget.unselectedWidget[ind]
          ? widget.selectedWidget[ind]
          : widget.unselectedWidget[ind];
      bool isSelected =
          _choosedButtons[ind] == widget.unselectedWidget[ind] ? true : false;

      if (widget.shouldBeJustOneSelected) {
        _choosedButtons = deepCopyList(widget.unselectedWidget);
      }
      _choosedButtons = deepCopyListElement(_choosedButtons, newElement, ind);

      widget.onPressed(newElement, isSelected);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: buildList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Just let me know if you think I can improve it in any way, thanks :D